# Laravel 5.8 route for controller inside module directory

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.8

I would like to have controllers in separate directories according modules which belongs to. For example I would like to make structure **Controllers/Auth/GithubLoginController.php** I have correct namespace for controller App\Http\Controllers\Auth

I have the following route

```
Route::get('/github/login', 'GithubLoginController@login')->name('github.login');
```

and this throws me an error:

> **Class App\Http\Controllers\GithubLoginController does not exist**

How to tell Laravel to find the controller inside the auth directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Route::get('/github/login', 'Auth\GithubLoginController@login')->name('github.login');
```

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks a lot.